# No comma between journal name and journal number

Tags: bibtex, natbib

De Gruyter requires no comma between journal name and journal number. So rather than

```
Bird, Steven, and Klein, Ewan 1994 Phonological analysis in typed feature systems. Computational Linguistics, 20 3: 455–491.
```

they want:

```
Bird, Steven, and Klein, Ewan 1994 Phonological analysis in typed feature systems. Computational Linguistics 20 3: 455–491.
```

I looked at the `.bst` file I have and found that there is an `output.nonull` that probably is responsible for the comma, but I do not know how to influence it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{SM.bib}
  @article{a, author={Max Meier}, title={My first paper}, journal={Journal of Googelology},
    volume=3123, number=1, pages={3--45}, year=2009}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}


\bibliographystyle{degruyter-hsk} 

\bibliography{SM}
\end{document}
```

De Gruyter `.bst` is here: [degruyter-hsk.bst](http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/transfer/degruyter-hsk.bst)

Comment: That's their problem, not yours as the author. If their `.bst` doesn't match their own guidelines, they should fix it themselves.

Comment: The linked file doesn't seem to be official or indeed widely-distributed, and I also can't find any rules for the publisher you mention. Could you give us some detail of the exact target publication and where we can find their submission/layout info?

Comment: BibTeX programming is a nasty thing and to be honest i am really not in to it very much. There is this online sources regarding the subject, which i find quite useful: www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxhak.pdf. And: Alltough Alex is right, you can still give it a try to rebuild the bst with `makebst` (and tweaking this one thing you want to achive).

Comment: @Alex: Unfortunately not. De Gruyter is a premium publisher and the type setting is done in India (or somewhere near it). The publisher/editors require us to deliver manuscripts that adhere to their rules. They do not provide .bst files. I am just using this old style file, which happend to work for earlier submissions.

Comment: @Mico: I tired to do this (without knowing what I am doing), but bibtex complains: `ptr=1, stack=
\hspace{1em} 
---the literal stack isn't empty for entry a
while executing---line 1533 of file degruyter-hsk.bst`

Comment: @StefanMüller Well, I've published enough things with those "premium" publishers. You spend hours and hours preparing the perfect tex file and then everything is messed up by some subcontractor somewhere. Anyway, as mentioned above, `makebst` is probably the way to go...

Comment: Where can I download "degruyter-hsk.bst" by the way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here's a [patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_file) for the above `degruyter-hsk.bst`. In the `FUNCTION {article}` you need to add a line with `add.blank` before `format.vol.num.pages`:

```
--- degruyter-hsk.bst.old   2013-07-05 11:04:03.000000000 +0200
+++ degruyter-hsk.bst   2013-08-08 19:52:57.000000000 +0200
@@ -909,6 +909,7 @@
     { journal
       emphasize
       "journal" output.check
+      add.blank
       format.vol.num.pages output
     }
     { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really made my day. I spent a lot of time on this `.bst` file and I am very glad that I did not have to start over with makebst. As for the premium publishers: We started Language Science Press, which is OA and free, but there are still some projects running with the old publishers. The current one is a handbook project which started in 2005! Thanks again!